# How can I improve my flow code with conditionals and loops with observables RXJS in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, rxjs6

I am newbie with RXJS Observables and I am trying to improve the next code, this code function well so I've written this code thinking on linear programming but I think is not correct, the buttton call this function :

```
  submitLocations() {
    var locationsToAdd = this.locationsChecked.filter(item => !this.myLocations.some(other => item.id === other.id));
    var locationsToDelete = this.myLocations.filter(item => !this.locationsChecked.some(other => item.id === other.id));

    if (locationsToAdd.length > 0) {
      this.addLocations(this.createLocationsToEdit(locationsToAdd));
    }
    if (locationsToDelete.length > 0) {
      this.deleteLocations(this.createLocationsToEdit(locationsToDelete));
    }
    const startIndex = this.navCtrl.getActive().index - 1;
    this.navCtrl.remove(startIndex, 2).then(() => {
      this.events.publish('dniNameUpdated', true);
      this.navCtrl.pop().then(() => this.presentToast(`Se han actualizado tus localizaciones favoritas`))
    })
  }

private createLocationsToEdit(locations) {
    let locationsToEdit = {} as LocationLegacyEdit;
    locationsToEdit.locations = [];
    locations.forEach((res: LocationModel) => {
      locationsToEdit.locations.push(res.id);
    });
    return locationsToEdit;
  }
```

As you see, in my code, I have 2 lists to add and delete locations, if it lenght is more than 0 I have to call my services with : addLocations and deleteLocations.

```
    private addLocations(locations: LocationLegacyEdit) {
    this._sp.addFavoriteLocationList(locations).subscribe(() => {
    }, error => console.log(error))
  }

  private deleteLocations(locations: LocationLegacyEdit) {
    this._sp.deleteLocationOteroUserList(locations).subscribe(() => {
    }, error => console.log(error))
  }
```

And my services that return observable are these:

```
    deleteLocationOteroUserList(locations: LocationLegacyEdit): Observable<any> {
    let url = URL_SERCAE + '/instances/favorites-locations';
    return this.http.request('DELETE', url, {
      body: locations
    })
  }

  addFavoriteLocationList(locations: LocationLegacyEdit): Observable<any> {
    let url = URL_SERCAE + '/instances/favorites-locations';
    return this.http
      .post(url, locations)
      .map(res => {
        return res['result'];
      })
  }
```

COuld someone help me, how can I improve this flow ?, I am not sure if Should I write 1 service to combine ADD with DELETE or Should I write this in my component  with conditional to continue if length is 0.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just a quick style comment, having variables and methods with the same name is not very clean and usually means one of both is named "incorrectly". For example `deleteLocations` is a perfectly fine name for a method because it obviously describes an action, but for the variable containing the locations you need to delete I'd go with something like `locationsToDelete`.

Comment: Be careful when you serialize requests to the server like you did. In your example, if you have 100 addresses to add/remove, then requests will run asynchronously resulting in reaching the maximum requests per domain depending on which browser you are using. Another potential issue is adding an address that is also present in the list to addresses to delete.

Comment: in `addLocations` and `deleteLocations`, instead of using a `forEach`, you should use rxjs operators. Something like : `merge(locations.map(loc => this._sp.addFavoriteLocation(loc.id))).subscribe(/* manage results */);` which will execute an array of observables based on your http requests. Of course, `merge` is here an example and may not be the more efficient operator depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

When working with RxJS, moving towards a one-way data-flow is recommended. This would mean that the service has a Observable that anyone can subscribe to to get the list of locations (which would emit any time there is a change). Also, this would mean that the add and delete functions will no longer return an observable (because anyone who needs the updated value should already be subscribed to the main observable).

```
class locationService {
    // This is a BehaviorSubject so the service can easily emit new values
    //  but outside of this service, all changes must happen by calling functions
    // so we will only expose an Observable 
    private locationSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Location[]>([])
    get locations$() {
        return locationSubject.asObservable();
    }

    addFavoriteLocation(location: Location) {
        this.http.post(...).subscribe(res=>{
            if(/*res indicates success*/) {
               this.locationSubject.next([...this.locationSubject.value, location])
            }
        })
    }
}
```